# How to install UML2Tools in Rational Business Developer

Tags: eclipse, uml

Am trying to install Eclipse UML2Tools plugin, in Rational Business Developer 7.5.1

Most compatible version seems UML2Tools 0.8.0 - but am unable to get it working.

I could not get UML2Tools working by neither from the local update site mechanism, nor by placing it in dropins folder.

One of the error reported when updating using local site was:

Cannot find a solution where both Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.emf/[2.4.0.v200806091234,2.4.0.v200806091234]] and Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.emf/[2.4.0.v200808251517,2.4.0.v200808251517]] can be satisfied.

Then I forced UML2Tools in RBD 7.5.1, by placing in its features and plugins folder. This got it working, but on trying class diagram -- the diagram generated had large shapes, was laid out incorrectly, and classes were not connected.

What can be done to get UML2Tools working in RBD 7.5.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would question if there is not some UML2Tools already running which is conflicting with your installation.  I would just use eclipse on the side or get RSM/RSA.  According to the documentation RBD can do model transformations from ULM2 which means it already has the emf/gmf/equinox libraries somewhat installed.  Who knows how IBM crippled RBD to not provide more UML2 features.  If you really want to dig I would us the plug-in registry view to see what is running at a high-level. (Takes time to open) type in equinox, my RSA ofcourse has many plug-ins around UML2 etc.

[image: plug0in viewer]

Comment: i gave it up - but i believe this was the case - that there were other plugins conflicting. thanks.